# Save the atjobs command time records for Backup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I wonder if there is a simple way to save the time records that has been applied by Atjobs, because I need to save the times already defined by Atjobs when making a system switch for example.

As far as I understand Atjobs will save its records in the folder `/var/spool/cron/atjobs`.

Knowing these records, can I copy the generated files inside this folder without problems or won't the Atjobs recognize these files?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely copy the at job files from /var/spool/cron/atjobs to back them up or migrate them to another system. The at jobs are stored as plain text files with the .a extension and named after the Unix timestamp of their scheduled run time.

As long as you preserve the file name and contents, copying these job files to another system's /var/spool/cron/atjobs directory should allow those jobs to run as originally scheduled. When the atd daemon is started, it scans the atjobs directory and reads the queued job files to know what jobs are scheduled. So as long as the file names and contents match what atd expects, copying job files over should work fine.

Don't forget to preserve file name based on scheduled timestamp, job details/script inside the file and file permissions.